# Ошибка Invalid syntax без видимой причины

Tags: python

```
a =[]
n= 20

min = 1000
for i in range (0,n):
    a.append (int(input())
if (a[i] %2 == 0) and (a[1] < min): 
              min = a[i]

print(min)
```

выделяет двоеточие после min) и пишет syntax error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка из-за того, что в строке с `append` закрыто на одну скобку меньше чем должно быть.

Ругается на двоеточие, а не на отсутствующую скобку, потому что из-за незакрытой скобки Python считает `if` частью составного выражения вида:

```
a.append ( int(input()) if (a[i] %2 == 0) and (a[1] < min) else something )
```

Но так как вместо `else` попадается двоеточие, то ругается на двоеточие.

Comment: Благодарю, проголосовал бы за, да репутации нет

Comment: Можно принять ответ (галка под "голосовалкой")